# Extract certificates from PFX file _without_ using OpenSSL

Tags: pfx

I found an [answer that uses OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer/405545#405545), but I'm on Windows, and I don't have it easily to hand. Is there a way (e.g. using CERTUTIL or VBScript) to see the certificates in a .PFX file?

If I use "certutil -dump", it asks for the password for the key. I don't want the key, and the certificate's supposed to be public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a PFX file, both the private key *and* the certificate are encrypted (using the same password). If you do not know the password, you won’t get the certificate. If you know it, `certutil -dump` should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Get-PfxData` from `pkiclient`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/get-pfxdata?view=win10-ps

Example:

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "localhost" -Force -AsPlainText
$mypfx = Get-PfxData -FilePath C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\localhost.pfx -Password $mypwd   
$mypfx
$mypfx.EndEntityCertificates
```

If you have the certificate in store and need a `.sst` (Microsoft serialized certificate store), `.cer` (CERT) or `.p7b` (PKCS#7) file you can use `Export-Certificate` from `pkiclient` (Or Export it via MMC without the private key).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps

Example for exporting IIS Express generated localhost certificate:

Start mmc.exe.

Then go to:

File -> Add or Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> Add -> Computer account -> Local computer

Expand the Personal folder and you will see your localhost certificate.

Double click, go to Details and copy the certificate Thumbprint.

Then run the command:

```
$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\{YourThumbprint})
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\localhost.cer
```

Note: If you need a certificate from your current user then replace `LocalMachine` with `CurrentUser` in the above command.