# Getting information from PFX file

Tags: pfx

Is there a utility to get information from PFX files like for example to get the private key? How is a PFX structured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer/405545#405545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KeyPal](http://www.jensign.com/KeyPal/index.html) utility will help you partially.

Refer Pkcs#12 options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command.

> keytool -list -keystore path of pfx file in quotes -storepass password of pfx file in quotes

It will display how many certificates keychain it has along with all details one by one