# How to add digital signature to my project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, certificate

When I try to run mi compiled application Windows advertises that the APP don't have any signature and asks if I really want to run my app.

I don't know the reason wich causes that but I think to avoid this I need a digital signature, so from the web I followed this steps:

I've created my own cert with the makecert tool from Windows SDK's, following a example with this code:

```
makecert -r -pe -a sha1 -n "CN=name, E=name@Hotmail.com, C=US" -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2050 -ss My
```

Then I can see my own certificate in the "Personal" Folder:

[image]

Now I've exported the certificate with this command:

```
certutil -exportPFX -p "Password" my 586a7358ebdce8854def26875f0f38ab "C:\Test.pfx"
```

But when I opened the signing tab in my project setings and choosed "Select from file...", VS says this:

```
The selected certificate is not valid for code-signing. Choose another certificate file.
```

[image]

I did bad something? I don't know how to correctly code-sign my project,
maybe I need a ".cer" certificate instead a ".pfx" certificate?
then how I can generate a valid CER certificate?

Comment: This question provides an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer (look at the accepted answer on that page)

Comment: Finally I did it via commandline, thanks for comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137260/how-to-locate-new-certification-using-certutil/16138972#16138972