# SSL Certificate for azure website from godaddy

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I purchased an SSL certificate from godaddy and the file provided by them is .crt format. my website is hosted on Azure and Azure portal accepts file in .pfx and .cer format for SSL. The .crt file is not accepted. As the .crt file is not accepted, I am unable to bind it with the domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .pfx to .cer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer)

Comment: also https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key)